# How to implement transformSchema in Transformer with pivot

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I have this code:

```
override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {
  df.groupBy($(idCol))
    .pivot("period")
    .agg($(aggfunct).toAggFunction)
    .na.fill(0)
    .orderBy($(idCol))
}
```

That is implemented in some custom `Transformer`. How can I implement the 
`transformSchema(schema: StructType)` function if I don't know the resulting columns?